# Rails RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Yet when run rake:routes it appears to be there:

```
     users GET    /users(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
            POST   /users(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
       user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
   sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
    session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
     signup        /signup(.:format)         {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
    contact        /contact(.:format)        {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
      about        /about(.:format)          {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
       help        /help(.:format)           {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"help"}
       root        /(.:format)               {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}

Here are the routes from routes.rb:

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]


  match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  match '/contact', to: 'pages#contact'
  match '/about', to: 'pages#about'
  match '/help', to: 'pages#help'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible that you are not passing the **:id** param in your route, which is why the route is not matched, since **:id** is required:

```
session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
```

Note: The parentheses around the :format param mean that it is optional.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error as well.But the reason is the little mistake that  in the view page  I write
     `<%= form_for(:session,url:session_path) do |f| %>`
  which I less the last 's'  of 'sessions'.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an error I was running into when running through http://ruby.railstutorial.org/, and it turned out that I had left a few things out of routes.rb.  The addition of the resource route is accompanied by the following two additional routes:

```
match '/signin', :to => 'sessions#new'
match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'
```

It's hard to see because the first route in that group is already there, so I had just glossed over the group (several times) as already being there.

Comment: _Why_ does adding this fix the route?  It's not about the URL.  If I change the URL to /signoutXXX it still succeeds.  Apparently it's about the action, because if I change it to #destroyXXX it fails.  The mere fact that _something_ is going to 'sessions#destroy' seems to make all the difference, so why doesn't a simple `resources :sessions` do the job?

Answer (score -1):

`resources controller` adds map to method

`{:action=>"method", :controller=>"controller"}`

when in your case the rails seemed to ask for explicitly the map as

`{:controller=>“controller”, :action=>“method”}`

The `:controller` is before `:action`

This also answered Noach's question why `match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'` has to exist, if you rake:routes you will see it added

`{:controller=>“sessions”, :action=>“destroy”}` while there is already a 
`{:action=>“destroy”, :controller=>“sessions”}` added by `resources sessions`

Comment: ruby hashsmaps are not ordered.